# How to add a line break to flexbox, row, no-wrap?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

When I resize the browser window I want the number of the columns to change while boxes are flexible with `flex-wrap: no-wrap;`.

So I thought it could be the solution if I add breaks after `divs` and disable/able some of the breaks from CSS with `@media`. It looks like it is impossible to add a line-break while `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` is active.

I am a newbie and I want to learn CSS at its best, therefore, I am trying myself with getting responsive structures in different situations.

I have tried `<br>` tag, `space-white: pre;` and `preline`. I've also tried setting additional parent element to `display: inline-block;`. But they didn't work for me. I want to do it with only `HTML` and `CSS` if possible. But it isn't a mandatory limitation.

My html and css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.car{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

.carParent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
  <body>

<div class="carParent">
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
  <div class="car"><h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3></div>
</div>

  </body>
```

Comment: please add a sample of your code for reference, it's much easier for us to help

Comment: No this is not possible to change line in flexbox without using `flex-wrap: wrap;` try with float or inline-block

Comment: @MateuszJuruś I added the code. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I tried, didn't work.

Comment: If you want flex items to wrap then set flex-wrap to wrap, that's the purpose of the rule

Comment: @UlviDamirli please what you have tried ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I have created additional parent divs for every 3 divs and set it to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

You have `flex-wrap:wrap` for that, and to make it full responsive I've improved your code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.carParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; /* try also: space-between or center */
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto; /* to center in screen -- optional */
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.car {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="carParent">
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <h3>SOME TEXT AND IMAGE</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't want to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` because of boxes will not be responsiveness.

Comment: That's a lie. I can make your boxes full responsive your code is not  full responsive at the momewnt

Comment: then could you please help me? I want them to be responsive and change number of the columns as browser size goes narrower